# Data placed into array correctly but is not there when array is printed

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, hashtable

I'm implementing my own hash table and I am running into the following problem: when I insert my node(s) into the table, they are not printed out when I loop through the array. I am using an array of arrays as the underlying data structure and the logic is as follows:

- I pass my node to an insert function. This function, based on the
  type of data in my node, calls the appropriate hash function provided
  by the C++ STL.
- Then, I mod the hash value returned by the size of
  my hash table and use that to determine which array to place the
  node.
- I also have an array of arrays of booleans (the same size as my
  hash table) that I use to check whether a specific spot in my hash
  table already has data in it.
- If it does, I simply keep looping till
  an empty spot is found.

Like I said before, the problem is that the data is inputed correctly into the array (I've checked that with print statements), but when I print the array, nothing is outputted. I have also checked if my object is being constructed correctly (again, with print statements), but everything is looking fine. I've included the full code below. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
        ///////START OF NODE.H///////////
        #ifndef NODE_H
        #define NODE_H
        #include <iostream>
        template <typename T>
        class HashTable;

        template <typename T>
        class Node
        {
            friend class HashTable<T>;

            private:
                T data;

            public:
                Node(T Data): data(Data)
                {
                    std::cout << "In the node constructor" << std::endl;
                }

                Node() 
                {
                    decltype(data) {};
                }

                T getData() const
                {
                    return data;
                }
        };
        #endif
        //////////////////////END OF NODE.H////////////////////




        /////START OF HASHTABLE.H///////
        #ifndef HASHTABLE_H
        #define HASHTABLE_H
        #include "Node.h"
        #include <iostream>
        #include <array>
        #include <functional>
        #include <typeinfo>
        #include <string>
        const int TABLE_SIZE=5;
        template <typename T>
        class HashTable
        {
            private:
                std::array<std::array<Node<T>, TABLE_SIZE>, TABLE_SIZE> hashTable;
                std::array<std::array<bool, TABLE_SIZE>, TABLE_SIZE> spots;

            public:
                HashTable()
                {
                    for(int index=0;index<spots.size();++index)
                    {
                        for(int position=0;position<spots.at(index).size();++position)
                        {
                            spots.at(index).at(position)=false;
                        }
                    }
                }

                int hashFunction(Node<T> Node)
                {
                    auto key=Node.getData();

                    std::hash<decltype(Node.getData())> hash_function {};

                    int hash=hash_function(key);

                    if(hash < 0)
                    {
                        hash*=-1;
                    }

                    //std::cout << "The hash value return by the STL hash function for the key " << key << " is " << hash << std::endl;

                    if(hash > TABLE_SIZE)
                    {
                        hash%=TABLE_SIZE;
                    }

                    std::cout << "The hash value for the key " << key << " is " << hash << std::endl;

                    return hash;
                }

                void insert(Node<T> Node)
                {
                    int hashValue=hashFunction(Node);

                    auto location=hashTable.at(hashValue);

                    std::cout << "Going to insert " << Node.getData() << std::endl;

                    for(int index=0;index<location.size();++index)
                    {
                        if(spots.at(hashValue).at(index)==false)
                        {
                            std::cout << "Found a spot that is not taken!" << std::endl;

                            std::cout << "The size of the data at the spot in the array before we insert is: " << location.at(index).getData().size() << std::endl;

                            location.at(index)=Node;

                            std::cout << "The size of the data at the spot in the array after we insert is: " << location.at(index).getData().size() << std::endl;

                            std::cout << "The data that is in the spot in the array: " << location.at(index).getData() << std::endl;

                            std::cout << std::endl;

                            spots.at(hashValue).at(index)=true;

                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                bool contains(Node<T> Node)
                {
                    int hashValue=hashFunction(Node);

                    auto location=hashTable.at(hashValue);

                    auto result=find_if(begin(location), end(location), [Node] (const auto & element) {return element.getData()==Node.getData();});

                    if(result!=end(location))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }

                    return false;
                }

                int getSize() const
                {
                    int size {};

                    for(int index=0;index<hashTable.size();++index)
                    {
                        size+=hashTable.at(index).size();
                    }

                    return size;
                }

                void print()
                {
                    std::cout << "In the print function" << std::endl;

                    for(int index=0;index<hashTable.size();++index)
                    {
                        //std::cout << hashTable.at(index).size() << std::endl;

                        for(int position=0;position<hashTable.at(index).size();++position)
                        {                   
                            std::cout << hashTable.at(index).at(position).getData().size() << std::endl;
                        }
                    }

                    /*
                    for(int index=0;index<spots.size();++index)
                    {
                        for(int position=0;position<spots.at(index).size();++position)
                        {
                            if(spots.at(index).at(position)==true)
                            {
                                std::cout << "There should be some data here" << std::endl;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    */
                }
        };
        #endif
        ////////////END OF HASHTABLE.H//////////



       ////////////START OF MAIN.CPP///////////
             #include "HashTable.h"
             #include <cstdlib>
             #include <random>
             #include <algorithm>
             using namespace std;                 
             int main()
             {
                HashTable<string> hash_table;

                hash_table.insert(Node<string>("Java"));

                hash_table.insert(Node<string>("C++"));

                hash_table.insert(Node<string>("C#"));

                hash_table.insert(Node<string>("Latex"));

                hash_table.insert(Node<string>("Python"));

             }
        /////////////END OF MAIN.CPP/////////////
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One error is in your  `insert(Node<T> Node)` function on these line:

```
    auto location=hashTable.at(hashValue);
    //...
    location.at(index) = Node;
```

The `location` should be a reference not a copy.  What is happening is that you're making changes to a local `location`, and not the actual `location` that the hash table uses.  Thus none of your changes "stick".

The line above should be this:

```
    auto& location=hashTable.at(hashValue);  // <-- note that auto is a reference
    //...
    location.at(index) = Node;
```

Now you are assigning the returned reference to a reference.

Also, I highly recommend you use a debugger, as this error could have been easily diagnosed if you stepped through your code to see what was being done.

Comment: Ah, yes, thank you! I will definitely be using a debugger in the future!

Comment: Well, I'll give you credit for actually using `C++` containers to implement your hash table, instead of the usual post using eye-boggling and hard to diagnose manual memory management.

Answer (score 0):

in `HashTable::insert` this line:

```
auto location = hashTable.at(hashValue);
```

makes a copy of a `Node`. You then operate on and store in the copy, not the node in `hashTable`. Taking a reference to the node

```
auto & location = hashTable.at(hashValue);
```

should fix it.